# BASH. How to insert in the same time " and ' in

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array in my `bash` script. And I need to insert in the same time two quotas symbols this " and this '.

My script

```
arr=(1 2 3)
for i in ${arr[@]}
do 
  darr+=("'${arr[$i]}',")
  echo "${darr[@]}"
done
```

Result of this script

```
'1', '2', '3',
```

But I need a little bit different result. Something like this:

```
"'1'", "'2'", "'3'",
```

I tried this construction `darr+=("\"'${arr[$i]}'\",")` but in result I see this:

```
\"'1'\", \"'2'\", \"'3'\",
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `i` is the value from the array you want, not the index.

Comment: Also, cannot reproduce using the code shown; no backslashes appear in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a loop, just use `printf`:

```sh
arr=(1 2 3)
printf -v str "\"'%s'\", " "${arr[@]}"
echo "$str"

"'1'", "'2'", "'3'",
```

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to the next one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arr=(1 2 3)
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
  darr+=("\"'$i'\"")
  echo "${darr[@]}"
done
```

The result is:

```
"'1'" "'2'" "'3'"
```